# PHP - CURL Errors occasionally (select/poll returned error)

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I've got a cron script which connects to a remote server and sends data, lots of data each day.

But like 30%-40% of the CURL requests are failing with the following CURL_error: "select/poll returned error"

what can cause such an error? since the code works most of the time.

Comment: Are you able to check if server where you send data doesn't return error like reached memory limits or you don't send to much data in one chunk to handle by server